# WPF Menuitems align left?

Tags: wpf

[image]

I want to display the menuitems to the right side of the Main menu. Currently its displayed to the left.

```
  <Menu Name="menu1" Width="800" Margin="0,0,0,670">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
    </Menu>


 <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Content="{Binding}" />                       
                </DataTemplate>                    
            </Setter.Value>               
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change orientation/location of menuitem in menubar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687086/how-to-change-orientation-location-of-menuitem-in-menubar)

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking - do you want the file/edit items to be aligned to the right of the menu bar or the Open/Close items to be right aligned to the file menu item.

Comment: Hi Leom, I want the Open/Close to the right side of the File Menu

Comment: No duplicate. His menus showed just left aligned without any obvious reason. The accepted answer below was the solution for me to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be a configuration problem with your local windows machine (check if this behavior appears in other programs too). If yes, you have two possibilities to fix this:

**Choice 1**

- Win+R
- Enter "shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}", press Ok
- Under "Other" change Right-Handed to Left-Handed, press Ok

Your menus should open left-aligned.

**Choice 2**

- Open your registry and change the following entry:
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\MenuDropAlignment]
  to "0"
- Reboot

Comment: Thanks, that helped me with my touchscreen laptop.  Since it's touchscreen, it was setup to use right hand display of menus.

Comment: Seems to have been same for me. Then MS-Accounts synced it to all my devices. What is the purpose of right hand for touchscreen, I don't understand this. Is there any possible advantage of using right hand menus with touchscreens?

Comment: Ok, commenting my own comment. Menu alignment seems to be more Stylus than Touch related. Then having your palm on the screen menus might be better aligned in the opposite direction. Makes sense, still don't want.