# Sub-MenuItems seem to align right by default

Tags: xaml

Every time I use a menu with MenuItems, the sub-MenuItems align right by default. They do so no matter what I put for the HorizontalAlignment property. Even when I type a relatively simple example:

```
<Grid>
  <Menu Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
      <MenuItem Header="_New" />
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</Grid>
```

The "New" MenuItem aligns right relative to the "File" MenuItem. For what it's worth, it looks normal in the preview using Visual Studio, just not when I actually run it.

Answer (score 0):

There is space on the left hand side of the text to accompany the **IsCheckable** checkbox. You can see it in action using the following code:

```
<MenuItem Header="_New" IsCheckable="True"/>
```

If you want to remove this spacing, consider using a **[ControlTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/12/27/wpf-control-templates-an-overview.aspx)** to override the default MenuItem template.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, apparently I didn't search hard enough for other posts with the same problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393806/wpf-menuitems-align-left) user had the same problem (and did a better job of illustrating it), and the solution posted there worked perfectly. The issue was that since my computer is optimized for touch technology, the default is to align sub-MenuItems so that right-handed users' hands won't get in the way.