# WPF Sub-MenuItem Opening on the Left Instead of the Right

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, menuitem

I have set up a simple sample menu.

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem Header="Top Menu">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1">
      <MenuItem Header="Sub Menu 2" />
    </MenuItem>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Sub Menu 2 is opening on the left instead of the expected right side of the menu.  I would expect this behaviour if the menu was near the edge of the screen, but window is centered on the screen and not near any edge.

Is there a property that controls where a `MenuItem` opens on the screen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Does this happen on other applications on your system as well?

There's a registry setting in the value `MenuDropAlignment` in the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` that controls it system-wide. You might just check to make sure that it is set to 0 instead of 1.

More info can be found [in this article](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/786-menus-open-left-right-side.html).

Comment: That was the problem.  It was on my work computer and no other machine had that same setting.  Strange how that switch was flipped.  I was sure it was my program instead of my computer.  Thanks!

Comment: This may happen on tablet computers as a default for right-handed users, so their hand doesn't cover the menu. If on Windows 10, click on the Start menu and type **"Tablet PC Settings"** and push enter. It'll search for the correct app. On the second tab "Other", choose "Left-handed", and it'll go back to normal. I thought initially this behaviour was because I had my menu inside a ViewBox element, but it was this tablet pc settings instead.