# Is it possible to make sure a context menu with multiple options open to the right by default

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

My WPF context menu code is:

```
<ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding DefaultText}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding SetAsDefault}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Set As Default For" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Names}}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="MenuItem"> 
                  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                  <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SetAsDefault}" />
                  <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
             </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

and by default when I hover over "Set As Default For" my Names appear to the left of my context menu

[image]

Is it possible to make this open to the right by default unless it obviously cant because of the limitations of the screen

Comment: have you tried playing with the Placement property ?

Comment: @SamTheDev on what object would I find the `Placement` property? a little more info would help

Comment: Maybe this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454482/wpf-sub-menuitem-opening-on-the-left-instead-of-the-right

Comment: @keyboardP yes the answer to that question is related.. I tried editing my registry value to the one suggested but the menu still opens to the left

Comment: after a restart the context menu seemed to open the correct way.. strange